# How to print out an ArrayList in the order it was added

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

calling record() method throughout my program. so if the user enters
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. In that order, it prints out 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. And ive tried enhanced for-loops, forloops that increment etc. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
ArrayList<Integer> playerMoves = new ArrayList<Integer>(20); 

    public void record(int value) {

    playerMoves.add(0, value);

    if(playerMoves.size() > 20) {
        playerMoves.remove(playerMoves.size() - 1);
    }
}


public void displayPlayerMoves() {

    int fullstopCount = 20;
    System.out.print(playerMoves.size() + " moves: ");

    for(int i = playerMoves.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        fullstopCount--;
        if(playerMoves.size() == fullstopCount) {
            System.out.print(playerMoves.get(i) + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.print(playerMoves.get(i) + ", ");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you are using `fullstopCount` it is initialised as `0` then you are doing `fullstopCount--` why?? and also you need to change `add` method as `playerMoves.add(value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding each element in the first position of the list:

```
playerMoves.add(0, value);
```

which means you are creating a list whose order is the reverse of the insertion order.

If you change it to:

```
playerMoves.add(value);
```

it will add each element to the end of the list, which will also cause the list to be printed in the order of insertion.

If you make that change, you should also change

```
if(playerMoves.size() > 20) {
    playerMoves.remove(playerMoves.size() - 1);
}
```

to

```
if(playerMoves.size() > 20) {
    playerMoves.remove(0);
}
```

since you want to remove the oldest move.

EDIT :

I just noticed that when you print the elements you iterate over the list in reverse order, but your loop has wrong indices. It should be :

```
int i = playerMoves.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

If you use that loop, you don't have to change the `record` method.

If you do change the order of the elements in the list, you can simplify your display method:

```
public void displayPlayerMoves() 
{
    System.out.print(playerMoves.size() + " moves: ");
    bool first = true;
    for(int value : playerMoves) {
        if (!first)
            System.out.print(", ");
        first = false;
        System.out.print(value);
    }
    System.out.print('.');
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it `add(value)`? What is `value` used for otw?

Comment: did you mean `playerMoves.add(value);` ?

Comment: Still prints 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. 
:(

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, typo :)

Comment: You also would want to remove element 0, not the last one, I'd guess, or you may as well not bother adding the element in the case where size is already 20.

Comment: value stores the users input

Comment: @user2878551 I had a typo - it should be `playerMoves.add(value);`

Comment: @Eran should i change the loop then?

Comment: @user2878551 Beside that, `displayPlayerMoves` seems to iterate over the list in reverse order, which you won't need if you store the elements according to insertion order.

Comment: @Eran mind coding an example? still not too sure what you mean. thanks heaps if you do :D

Comment: @Eran thanks heaps you legend!!! xoxoxox p.s i love that show off way of adding a fullstop at the end haha

Answer (score 1):

You should add values to the end, and remove old values from the start of the list:

```
playerMoves.add(value);     
if(playerMoves.size() > 20) {
    playerMoves.remove(0);
}
```

Note that removing from the start of the list is an `O(n)` operation for `ArrayList`; changing to `LinkedList` would be `O(1)`.

But if you are sticking with `ArrayList`, you should remove the 20th element before adding another, since adding the 21st element will cause the `ArrayList` to have to increase its capacity.

Answer (score 0):

your code has two flaws :

Adding at first index and printing in reverse order.

change adding element as :

```
 playerMoves.add(value);
```

and loop for printing as :

```
  for(int i =0; i <playerMoves.size(); i++) {
     // your code 
    }
```